# UIimage size is different from real image resolution (UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'am getting image from ARFrame and convert it to UIImage (`imageToSave`).

```
var imageToSave = convert(cmage:arFrameImage)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
```

I save to iOS album the `imageTosave`. When I print `imageToSave.size` I get *1080.0, 1920.0*. When I check the picture resolution (after importing it to my Mac) it is *1080.0, 1920.0*.

Then I draw something on this `imageToSave`.

```
let imageSize = imageToSave.size
let scale: CGFloat = 0
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, scale)
image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
let rectangle = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10)
UIColor.white.setFill()
UIRectFill(rectangle)

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
print("========Image size B)=======")
print(newImage!.size)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage!, nil, nil, nil);
```

When I print `newImage!.size` I get *1080.0, 1920.0* as expected. But When I check the picture resolution (after importing it to my Mac) it is *3240.0, 5760.0*. Why is the real (imported) image resolution different from `newImage!.size`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create at `scale = 0`, you're saving the image at the device's main screen scale - 3x in your case.

You're creating an image that is 1080x1920 *points* @3x - which is 3240 x 5760 *pixels*

If you want your final image to be 1080x1920, use `scale = 1`